# Spring MVC CORS: Connection refused

Tags: api, spring-mvc, cors

I created a simple end-point to get started with CORS in Spring MVC.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/items", method =  RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    HttpEntity<PagedResources<ItemResource>> items(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
        org.springframework.data.domain.Page<Item> items = itemService.findAll(pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<ItemResource>>(assembler.toResource(items), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
```

Then I tested my end point using Jquery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://test.dev:8080/api/items"
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(jqXHR){
    console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Testing using Guzzle (PHP):

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $response = $client->get('http://test.dev:8080/api/items');
```

Jquery AJAX and Guzzle work perfectly. But when I created a new Spring MVC application to make another test with my API, I encountered an error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://test.dev:8080/api/items":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Test call using RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
return restTemplate.getForObject("http://test.dev:8080/api/items", SampleResponse.class);
```

Where should I start to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use **JAX-RS Client API** and it works.

pom.xml:

```
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--resteasy-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Call web service using Jax-rs:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
SampleResponse items = client.target("http://test.dev:8080/api/items")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get(new GenericType<SampleResponse>(){});

client.close();
```